# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Video Production Stack Exchange](http://video.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I just wanted to take a moment to thank everyone that participates here, whether through asking questions or using your experience to provide answers.  You guys and gals are what make this community what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Smooth horizontal and vertical camera movement](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9786/smooth-horizontal-and-vertical-camera-movement)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What keywords to use when searching for a Maya plugin developer?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9872/what-keywords-to-use-when-searching-for-a-maya-plugin-developer)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Tools to combine a video with an animated logo](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/tools-to-combine-a-video-with-an-animated-logo)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to fix choppy/lagging video from Canon t3i?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9778/how-to-fix-choppy-lagging-video-from-canon-t3i)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to Setup Resolution and Frame Rate Between Two Cameras for Premiere Editting and YouTube](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/how-to-setup-resolution-and-frame-rate-between-two-cameras-for-premiere-editting)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Remote pan/tilt/zoom cameras that aren't expensive](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9835/remote-pan-tilt-zoom-cameras-that-arent-expensive)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Reliable way to burn VIDEO_TS folder on a DVD?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9876/reliable-way-to-burn-video-ts-folder-on-a-dvd)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to focus when recording video using a DSLR?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/how-to-focus-when-recording-video-using-a-dslr)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Low cost DIY high-speed video camera](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/low-cost-diy-high-speed-video-camera)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Problem of overview with my created closed caption in Premiere CC](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9886/problem-of-overview-with-my-created-closed-caption-in-premiere-cc)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Answer (score 2):

Note that the turn out here was a little low, and we fully expected it to be due to this coinciding so closely with the split. Thanks everyone that was able to participate for doing so, it's great to see folks diving in despite so many 'under construction' signs aloft.

I will chime in to add, Video seems to be doing a bit *better*, all around, than it was prior to the split and renaming. I don't have hard numbers just yet, but I will within the next month, and every sign right now points at participation in every way that we measure it staying the same or increasing (mostly increasing, if I'm looking at things correctly).

#### Beware of Jabberwockys offering stats on Area 51

Because of the re-branding and everything else that's been going on (migrations, etc) - stats that you see on the side bar and Area 51 are also bound to be a little (well, perhaps a lot) goofy - don't pay attention to it for the next 30 days or so. Video is doing *fine* and there's nothing to worry about - no post-op concerns other than some ongoing tag / etc cleanup.

Just a note, so that folks don't get to worrying about the future of the site - all looks good from where I'm sitting.